# React Native styled-components issue : typerror:_native.default.button is not a function

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I get the above error message in my phone after I try to render a button in my view using `styled.button` method.

Here's a piece of code using the `styled.button` method.

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const ButtonView = styled.button`
backgroundColor:red;
color:white;
border: 2px solid white;
borderRadius: 3px;
width:100%;
`;

const login = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor:"#2667C9",alignItems:"center"}}>
      <ButtonView>Go</ButtonView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default login;
```

The following is the error I get when running the code. I have no idea why this is happening, as the official documentation page suggests exactly this method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

React native doesn't understand a `button` component. You need to import Button from React native and style it

```
import { View , Button} from 'react-native';

const ButtonView = styled(Button)`
backgroundColor:red;
color:white;
border: 2px solid white;
borderRadius: 3px;
width:100%;
`;
```

or use the Uppercase character like `styled.Button`

```
const ButtonView = styled.Button`
    backgroundColor:red;
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    borderRadius: 3px;
    width:100%;
    `;
```

Comment: I tried both of the above methods before, but it didn't override any of the custom styles I passed to it.

Comment: @SandeepNeupane the styles you pass as props have impact only to the `View` (the wrapper) not the styled component `ButtonView` itself